# Specify new location for "cached-microdescs"?

Tags: configuration, help

I have a very small filesystem with very little space left (approx. 3-4MB), can I redirect the "cached-microdescs" -files to another place?
The problem is that the disc fills up to 100% after a short time.

There is plenty of space in a "volatile" area that I want to use, is there a problem that the "cached-microdescs" -files are wiped out due to a restart of the system?

Answer (score 1):

Tor doesn't support splitting your data directory like that, if you create a symlink to some other place Tor removes that symlink instead of using it.

In your situation, I'd suggest putting your entire datadirectory into the volatile storage area with a script for startup/shutdown to copy just the important parts of information (state file for clients, keys for relays) to permanent storage on boot/shutdown.